# How to get css from specified element of web page

Tags: html, css, web-developer-toolbar

I always wanted to know how to get css code from specified element of a web page
Some web sites have a elements that I like and want to add into my localhost page, for example: menu bar.I use inspect element in Google Chrome and I know how to get html code but now css of the element.
I looked at apple.com and I want to add that menu bar to my localhost sites.This is class for menu bar `<div class="globalnav-wrapper">`

Can you help me to get css code of this menu?My english is not got at all but I think you understand me.

Comment: if the site author has restricted the display of css you cannot view the css.Or else you try it in firefox and see

Comment: yes in firefox u can get the clear css

Comment: @Ninad Do you have a link on how to restrict the display of CSS? I didn't think that was even possible.

Answer (score 1):

navigate to resources tab after pressing F12 in chrome and then expand directory tree there you will see css right click on it and choose `save or save as`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the particular position and click 
          "Inspect element"
. In browser bottom you can see the selected div and right side can see the css. If you use firefox it will give more options

```
  globalnav-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
margin: 18px 0 0 -512px;
width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: This is code I added http://pastebin.com/tYv2XSJg And this is what I get  http://imageshack.us/f/407/g8xs.png/ To be sure, I made external css file

Comment: coppy all the below css for ul , ul.. that will correct the menu

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are using chrome:-

   $('div[class=globalnav-wrapper]')
2. If you are using Firefox then download firebug and firepath and then click on inspect with firepath and select CSS in dropdown of element page and write:-

   div[class=globalnav-wrapper]

   firefox is easier and better than chrome in finding the element from the       webpage.